# After changing configurations, how to execute to change the read-only mode of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

When I delete a storage group in Apache IoTDB, it prompts that the database is in read-only mode. I read over the questions that mentioned read-only problem, and already changed the configurations I need. However, the questions and the official guide both seems to not have the necessary command of switching mode after changing settings. So does anyone know how to (or how to tempt to) switch modes in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already changed all the settings you need, you can just execute `SET SYSTEM TO RUNNING` command in Apache IoTDB and see if the system can be restarted in normal mode.